# In HQL select registerFunction using Custom SQLdialect is not working

Tags: hibernate, hql, dialect

I have following HQL Query

```
StringBuilder selectBuilder = new StringBuilder(
    "select new support.dto.SrsRequirementStatus( s.id, sm.id, sm.name, "
    + "sr.id, sr.requirement, sr.reference, "
    + "sca.code_id, sca.code_name, spa.code_id, spa.code_name, ssa.code_id, ssa.code_name, "
    + "function('cr_min_query', s.id, 'SRS') as minuser, "
    + "function('cr_max_query', s.id, 'SRS') as maxuser ) "
    + "from SRS s "
    + "inner join s.domain d "
    + "inner join s.project p "
    + "inner join s.srsModule sm "
    + "inner join s.srsRequirements sr "
    + "inner join sr.category sca "
    + "inner join sr.priority spa "
    + "inner join sr.status ssa ");
StringBuilder whereCauseBuilder = new StringBuilder("where d.code_id = :domainId and p.project_id = :projectId ");
```

Using following Constructor

```
public SrsRequirementStatus( Integer srsId, Integer srsModuleId, String srsModuleName, 
        Integer requirementId, String requirement, String reference, String categoryId, String categoryName, 
        String priorityId, String priorityName, String statusId, String statusName, 
        String createdBy, String updatedBy ) {
    this.srsId = srsId;
    this.srsModuleId = srsModuleId;
    this.srsModuleName = srsModuleName;
    this.requirementId = requirementId;
    this.requirement = requirement;
    this.categoryId = Integer.valueOf( categoryId );
    this.priorityId = Integer.valueOf( priorityId );
    this.statusId = Integer.valueOf( statusId );
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    this.priorityName = priorityName;
    this.statusName = statusName;
    this.reference = reference;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}
```

And Custom SQLDialect class

```
public class CustomMySQLDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    public CustomMySQLDBDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction( "cr_max_query", new StandardSQLFunction( "cr_max_query" ) );
        registerFunction( "cr_min_query", new StandardSQLFunction( "cr_min_query" ) );
    }
}
```

Above mentioned HQL query generate following **Exception**
My **SQL** query similar to above **HQL** query returns two rows only without any **NULL** column value.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:309)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:174)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:144)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1091)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2328)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2194)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1476)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:573)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:298)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1821)
at support.DAO.ImplDeveloperDAO.findSrsRequirements(ImplDeveloperDAO.java:2046)
at support.service.ImplDeveloperService.findSrsRequirements(ImplDeveloperService.java:986)
at support.service.ImplDeveloperService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$90525943.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at support.service.ImplDeveloperService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c67eb653.findSrsRequirements(<generated>)
at support.controller.DeveloperController.findSrsDetails(DeveloperController.java:1694)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after making some changes in Custom MySQLDialect class

I changed

```
registerFunction("cr_max_query", new StandardSQLFunction("cr_max_query"));
```

to

```
registerFunction("cr_max_query", new StandardSQLFunction("cr_max_query", StringType.INSTANCE));
```

also removed **function** keyword from HQL Query and simply called function like this

```
[...]
+ "cr_min_query(s.id, 'SRS') as minuser, "
[...]
```

I was following https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/ where **function** keyword used, and it was not working in my case, don't know why?